# Magento 2: How to get default address as an array?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

I want to know how to get the default billing and shipping address of a customer as an array.

For example, the code below:

```
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customer_id);
$var_dump($customer-getData());
```

returns an array containing the customer information:

```
array(28) {
["entity_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["website_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["email"]=>
string(21) "roni_cost@example.com"
["group_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["increment_id"]=>
NULL
["store_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["created_at"]=>
string(19) "2018-03-24 21:49:15"
["updated_at"]=>
string(19) "2018-03-24 21:49:16"
["is_active"]=>
string(1) "1"
["disable_auto_group_change"]=>
string(1) "0"
["created_in"]=>
string(18) "Default Store View"
["prefix"]=>
NULL
["firstname"]=>
string(8) "Veronica"
["middlename"]=>
NULL
["lastname"]=>
string(8) "Costello"
["suffix"]=>
NULL
["dob"]=>
string(10) "1973-12-15"
["password_hash"]=>
string(99) "717e603af8497aafda595916332ee0c14a4e84ea59c4a6c3b92a010d747d5547:hHG7t2EQBdl6rZihGuCRxYAguCMCZOya:1"
["rp_token"]=>
string(32) "b7fc3de75f6bf6444abf72f2fb9bc157"
["rp_token_created_at"]=>
string(19) "2018-03-24 21:49:16"
["default_billing"]=>
string(1) "1"
["default_shipping"]=>
string(1) "1"
["taxvat"]=>
NULL
["confirmation"]=>
NULL
["gender"]=>
string(1) "2"
["failures_num"]=>
string(1) "0"
["first_failure"]=>
NULL
["lock_expires"]=>
NULL
}
```

Now, if I want to do the same for address:

```
$address = $this->addressFactory->create()->load($customer->getDefaultBilling);
$var_dump($address-getData());
```

This also returns an array, but it's way larger than the customer one to the point that it crashes the browser.

I just need the default billing and shipping address as an array without any other data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First initialize CustomerRepository and AddressCollectionFactory in your constructor

> \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
>
> \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\CollectionFactory

you can get your array like this

```
$customer_id = 5;

$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer_id);
$billing_address_id = $customer->getDefaultBilling();



$addressCollection = $this->addressCollectionFactory->create()
->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id",$billing_address_id)
    ->getFirstItem();
print_r($addressCollection->getData());
```

This will print the billing address array